# Cannot fix Map Fragment in Fragment NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am trying to show a **Map** in a Fragment but I always get this NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null
>   object reference

I knew there are many questions with this exception in this case but i can't find my mistake. I read any answer I have found.

Here is my Code:

```
public class DetailKarteFragment extends Fragment {

GoogleMap map;

static final LatLng brend = new LatLng(48.079, 8.157);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_karte, null, false);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    SupportMapFragment fmap = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (fmap == null) {
        fmap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        ft.add(R.id.map, fmap);
    }

    ft.commit();

    Marker brendMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(brend).title("Brend"));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(brend, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

    return v;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

and the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Route anzeigen"
        android:id="@+id/button_route_planen"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/secondary_100"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-48dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `map = (...).getMap()` line after `ft.commit()`. You are getting that exception because `FragmentManager` can't find a fragment which has not already been `add`ed or `replace`d into the container.

A better solution in my opinion would be:

```
SupportMapFragment fmap;
fmap = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

if (fmap == null) {
    fmap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    ft.add(R.id.map, fmap);
    ft.commit();
}
map = fmap.getMap();
```

Comment: fmap can surely be null, but in my example we are checking for nullity so no error should come. More important, to make this work you should change `<fragment >` in your layout into a `<FrameLayout>` and delete its `android:name` attribute.

Comment: Try also changing `getFragmentManager()` with `getChildFragmentManager()`, since we are using a Fragment inside a Fragment.

Comment: I tried all you said but nothing works. My map is always null... also i tried different combinations... Is there any other way to put a MapFragment in a Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the `GoogleMap` object map before checking if the `SupportMapFragment` even exists. I assume that this fragment hasn't been added yet, and you're invoking the `getMap()` method on a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old... But I just had this problem and I would like to share what was happening to me and the solution.

I was trying to put a MapFragment inside a fragment just like you. But I forgot to put the key in my manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

So, when this happens in a Activity, it throw an exception. That's great, because your app crashes and you can read the log and understand what you have to do! You get this message:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found. 
     Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> 
is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

It's very easy to find what needs to be done this way, right?

**But it doesn't happen when the MapFragment is inside another fragment!**

It only return a null fragment... just like the problem you have right now.

So just put the key in the Manifest and you will be fine! I hope Google fix this, because it took me some hours to find out what was wrong.